# Not able to show the textbox after clicking radio button in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am not able to show the hide box after clicking a radio button... i also attaching my code where i used the functionality...

Code:

```
<p:tab id="details" title="Company" titleStyleClass="tab" >
    <p:panel header="Details of the Applicant">
        <p:messages />
        <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="3" cellpadding="4" columnClasses="control-label">

            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['personal.applied']}"/>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{bean.applied}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="yes" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="no" />
                <f:ajax process="console"   update="details" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <p:spacer></p:spacer>

            <h:outputLabel  value="#{msg['personal.personName']}" rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}"></h:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText id="personName"    value="#{bean.personName}"   rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}"/>
            <p:watermark for="personName" value=" Favour is Sought " id="watermark2" />

            <h:outputText   value="# msg['personal.personName']} " rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}"/>
            <p:inputText id="personName" value="#{bean.personName}"  label="PersonName"  rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}" />
            <p:watermark for="PersonName" value="Applicant " id="watermark3" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</p:tab>
```

Please anyone help me how to resolve it....

Comment: It is Hidden box... Suppose when i click on 'no' radio button a input textbox should display bellow the radio button.but by default it should hidden..or if we click on 'yes' radio button, the input textbox should not display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to update a `<p:tab ..>` alone, since it has no Renderer attached.

You can however update the `<p:tabview ..>` Element, or (what I prefer) target the `<p:panel ...>` for the update.

This should work:

```
<p:tab id="details" title="Company" titleStyleClass="tab" >
    <p:panel id="panelIdForDemonstration" header="Details of the Applicant">
        <p:messages />
        <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="3" cellpadding="4" columnClasses="control-label">

            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['personal.applied']}"/>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{bean.applied}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="yes" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="no" />
                <f:ajax process="console"   update="panelIdForDemonstration" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <p:spacer></p:spacer>

            <h:outputLabel  value="#{msg['personal.personName']}" rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}"></h:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText id="personName"    value="#{bean.personName}"   rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}"/>
            <p:watermark for="personName" value=" Favour is Sought " id="watermark2" />

            <h:outputText   value="# msg['personal.personName']} " rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}"/>
            <p:inputText id="personName" value="#{bean.personName}"  label="PersonName"  rendered="#{bean.applied eq 'no'}" />
            <p:watermark for="PersonName" value="Applicant " id="watermark3" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</p:tab>
```